# How to set a minimum value when performing cumsum on a dataframe column (physical inventory cannot go below 0)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to perform a cumulative sum with a minimum value in python/pandas?

In the table below:

- the "change in inventory" column reflects the daily sales/new stock  purchases.
- data entry/human errors mean that **applying cumsum shows a negative inventory level of -5 which is not physically possible**.
- as shown by the "inventory" column, the data entry errors continue to be a problem at the end (100 vs 95).

dataframe

```
            change in inventory  inventory  cumsum
2015-01-01                  100        100     100
2015-01-02                  -20         80      80
2015-01-03                  -30         50      50
2015-01-04                  -40         10      10
2015-01-05                  -15          0      -5
2015-01-06                  100        100      95
```

One way to achieve this would be to use loops however it would be messy and there probably is a more efficient way to do this.

Here is the code to generate the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'change in inventory': {'2015-01-01': 100,
  '2015-01-02': -20,
  '2015-01-03': -30,
  '2015-01-04': -40,
  '2015-01-05': -15,
  '2015-01-06': 100},
 'inventory': {'2015-01-01': 100,
  '2015-01-02': 80,
  '2015-01-03': 50,
  '2015-01-04': 10,
  '2015-01-05': 0,
  '2015-01-06': 100}})

df['cumsum'] = df['change in inventory'].cumsum()
df
```

How to apply a cumulative sum with a minimum value in python/pandas to produce the values shown in the "inventory" column?

Comment: What exactly would you like the outcome to be, then? If there are errors in the column, there are several different heuristics one could use to attempt to rectify them.

Comment: The objective it to produce the same outcome as shown in the inventory column.

Comment: What would happen if you have multiple negative values?

Comment: @JohnGalt, negative values mean that future inventory levels are incorrect. In the last row you can see that 100 items of the product were added to the stock. This would mean that there are physically 100 items in the warehouse. In this example the inventory column shows the correct value of physical stock and the cumsum column underquotes the stock level by -5. Hope that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use looping, unfortunately:

```
lastvalue = 0
newcum = []
for row in df['change in inventory']:
    thisvalue =  row + lastvalue
    if thisvalue < 0:
        thisvalue = 0
    newcum.append( thisvalue )
    lastvalue = thisvalue

print pd.Series(newcum, index=df.index)
2015-01-01    100
2015-01-02     80
2015-01-03     50
2015-01-04     10
2015-01-05      0
2015-01-06    100
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the data, it can be far more efficient to loop over blocks with the same sign, eg. with large running sub-blocks all positive or negative. You only have to be careful going back to positive values after a run of negative values.

With a minimum limiting value as minS summing over vector:

```
import numpy as np
i_sign = np.append(np.where(np.diff(np.sign(vector)) > 0)[0],[len(vector)])
i0 = 1
csum = np.maximum(minS, vector[:1])
for i1 in i_sign:
    tmp_csum = np.maximum(minS, csum[-1] + np.cumsum(vector[i0:i1+1]))
    csum = np.append(csum, tmp_csum)
    i0 = i1
```

Final output in csum.

Answer (score 0):

very ugly solution

```
start = df.index[0]
df['cumsum'] = [max(df['change in inventory'].loc[start:end].sum(), 0) 
     for end in  df.index]
```

Comment: unfortunately this solution does not produce the same outcome as the "inventory" column. That is, the very last row is 95 and not 100.